# Matplotlib bar chart or similar with bars located at a specific x,y,angle

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

Is there a way to create a bar chart using matplotlib such that the bars are located at a specific x,y and at a specific angle? In the screenshot below, I just drew thick lines (to represent thin bars) in PowerPoint on top of the scatterplot.

It doesn't have to be a barchart necessarily, I just don't know the name of a plot that is like this. I thought about trying to mimic this with a quiver plot but wasn't sure how. Reason for wanting this is densely spaced points that have variable values (not monotonically increasing like in this example), and just coloring the scatter plot isn't visually elucidating trends of interest, even with different colormaps.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(25)
y = -x
z = x
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='viridis')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a canned way to do this, but you could, in a pinch, create your own function that draws [rectangles](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) to create this plot. For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

x = np.arange(25)
y = -x
z = x
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='viridis')

def slanted_bars(x, y, z, angle, ax):
    for xi, yi, zi in zip(x, y, z):
        ax.add_patch(Rectangle((xi, yi), 1, zi, angle))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='viridis')
slanted_bars(x, y, z, -45, ax)
```

[image]

You'd have to play with the color and shape of the rectangles to get something appealing, but it can do what you want.